# Change font size in quarto PDF

Tags: r, fonts, quarto

How to change the font-size in a quarto pdf document?

I tried with the following settings, but I did not see any changes in font size.

```
format:
  pdf: 
    documentclass: article
    geometry:
      - top=30mm
      - left=20mm
    fontfamily: libertinus
    fontsize: 16pt
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it is possible, but 16pt is not an available font size for an article; you can choose 10, 11, or 12pts. The `memoir` class has more, maybe you can try with that documentclass.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Just by trial-and-error I found that leaving the line with `documentclass: article` out, made changing fontsize possible:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document 
format:
  pdf:
    fontfamily: libertinus
    fontsize: 20pt

editor: visual
---
```

Comment: There are several problems with this: it is not an `article` class anymore, and it changes both the title and text size.

Comment: Thank you, @Maël. I have a change which does not change both title and text size in the same way.